# Bootstrap.navbar + Angular.routeProvider not working also not giving any error in chrome

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, route-provider

I have posted configuration for routeProvider and navigation for it using bootstrap nav-bar but its not working also
I don't get any error in google-chrome, url http://localhost:8080/collegeCap/#!/#collegeCap replaces with corresponding href but doesn't display content of the page.

```
var CollegeCapApp = angular.module('CollegeCapApp',
                ['ngAnimate','ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap','ngRoute']);


CollegeCapApp.config(function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider
        .when('/',{
                templateUrl : 'resources/pages/collegeCap.jsp'
        })
        .when('/collegeCap',{
                templateUrl : 'resources/pages/collegeCap.jsp'
        })
        .when('/collegeCapEvent',{
                templateUrl : 'resources/pages/collegeCapEvent.jsp'
        })
        .when('/collegeCapLogin',{
                templateUrl : 'resources/pages/collegeCapLogin.jsp'
        })
        .when('/collegeCapSignUp',{
                templateUrl: 'resources/pages/collegeCapSignUp.jsp'
        });

});


<div>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button"
       class="navbar-toggle"
       data-toggle="collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     </button>
     <a class="navbar-brand"  href="#">
       CollegeCapApplication
     </a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>
                <a href="#collegeCap" class="navbar-link">CollegeCap </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#collegeCapEvent" class="navbar-link"> CollegeCapEvent </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
           <li>
               <a href="#collegeCapSignUp" class="navbar-link">
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign up
               </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#collegeCapLogin" class="navbar-link">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-login"></span> Login
            </a>
         </li>
       </ul>
     </div>
   </nav>
</div>
~
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current set up you're asking angular to find a route named `#collegeCap` (which does not exist). Change your links to use `#!/routeName` e.g.:

```
<a href="#!/collegeCap" class="navbar-link">CollegeCap </a>
```

This tells angular that the part *after* the `#!/` should be processed by it's routing system and allow it to pick up the correct route.

**Another fix** is to reset the hash prefix back to the empty string by injecting `$locationProvider` into your module's `config` block and then setting the hash prefix as follows:

```
CollegeCapApp.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){

        // Add this line
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');

        $routeProvider
        .when('/',{
                templateUrl : 'resources/pages/collegeCap.jsp'
        })
        .when('/collegeCap',{
                templateUrl : 'resources/pages/collegeCap.jsp'
        })
        .when('/collegeCapEvent',{
                templateUrl : 'resources/pages/collegeCapEvent.jsp'
        })
        .when('/collegeCapLogin',{
                templateUrl : 'resources/pages/collegeCapLogin.jsp'
        })
        .when('/collegeCapSignUp',{
                templateUrl: 'resources/pages/collegeCapSignUp.jsp'
        });

});
```

and then your link would become:

```
<a href="#/collegeCap" class="navbar-link">CollegeCap </a>
```

Comment: Thanks.!!  Mattew Cawley

Comment: It's just a change made in angular v1.6 (assuming that's what you're using) [see here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#commit-aa077e8)

Comment: Has this fixed the problem?

Comment: Yes.  href="#!/*" Solved my issue.

Comment: Excellent, pleased it helped. Please mark as answer. :)